# I want to version my Spring API, how can I create a global constant for the url it only has to be changed in one place when the version changes?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, versioning

I have developed a SpringBoot REST API with many controllers, using @RequestMapping annotation. I want to create some kind of global variable to store:

```
String firstPartUrl = "/api/"

String apiVersion = "v1/"
```

So that in each controller's request mapping I can put:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(firstPartUrl + apiVersion + "/tubas")
public class TubaController {
}
```

This way, when the API version increases, I only need to change one value.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [spring rest api versioning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45438362/spring-rest-api-versioning)

Comment: I think this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20418450/8327893) will help you

Answer (score 1):

Add to application.properties

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("${firstPartUrl}" + "${apiVersion}" + "/tubas")
public class TubaController {
}
```

**application.properties**

```
firstPartUrl="/blabla"
apiVersion="/v2"
```

Comment: Hello, thanks, but when I tried to add this to controllers it didn't work, and then I removed it and put within the /signup controller method: System.out.println("${firstPartUrl}" + "${apiVersion}" + "/tubas")   and it printed: {firstPartUrl}${apiVersion}/tubas